# Converting String to Int while using reduce()

Tags: swift, type-conversion, reduce

I have code:

```
let number: String = "111 15 111"
let result = number.components(separatedBy: " ").map {Int($0)!}.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
```

First it takes given string and split into array of numbers. Next each number is converted to an integer and at the end all numbers are added to each other. It works fine but code is a little bit long. So I got the idea to get ride of map function and convert String to Int while using reduce, like this:

```
let result = number.components(separatedBy: " ").reduce(0, {Int($0)! + Int($1)!})
```

and the output is:

```
error: cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Int, (String, String) -> Int)'
```

Thus my question is: Why I cannot convert String to Integer while using reduce()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` second parameter is a closure with `$0` is the result and `$1` is the string. And instead of force unwrapping optional default value will be better.

```
let number: String = "111 15 111"
let result = number.components(separatedBy: " ").reduce(0, {$0 + (Int($1) ?? 0) })
```

Another alternative is with `flatMap` and `reduce` with `+` operator.

```
let result = number.components(separatedBy: " ").flatMap(Int.init).reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted. Btw, you can also write `flatMap(Int.init)` ...

Comment: @MartinR thanks, `flatMap(Int.init)` looks even better ;)

Comment: Hi, @Bilal. You should know, i'm not the one who downvote. Good answer, btw ;)

Comment: ok, I get it with single operations, but what if I have an array [2,20,4,6,1] and would like to know the result of let's say 2*20*4/6+1? How would closure looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is first argument in the closure. If you look at `reduce` declaration, first closure argument is `Result` type, which is `Int` in your case:

```
public func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, 
    _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

So the right code will be:

```
let result = number.components(separatedBy: " ").reduce(0, { $0 + Int($1)! })
```