# How to convert string to Int? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, integer, converters

I have this code, so I need how to convert spentBudget to Int?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! BudgetTableViewCell
    
    let budgetEvent: BudgetModel
    budgetEvent = budgetList[indexPath.row]
  
    cell.nameEventLabel.text = budgetEvent.eventName
    
    if let spent = budgetEvent.spentBudget{
        cell.spentBudgetLabel.text = spent
   }else{
        print("spent budget is empty")
    }
    
    let totalSpent = budgetList.compactMap{ $0.spentBudget }.reduce(0, +)
    self.spentBudget.text = String("$ \(totalSpent)")
    print("sum \(totalSpent)")
    return cell
}'''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting String to Int while using reduce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477947/converting-string-to-int-while-using-reduce)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you. The second comment was the right thing.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use `.reduce(0, +)`, I'd recommend a manual for loop since you don't seem to understand it. I you sill want to use `reduce()`, I'd use replace `compactMap{ $0.spentBudget}` with `compactMap{ Int($0.spendBudget) }`.

Comment: @Larme yes, that's helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String to int returns optional. For example:

```
let myInt2 = Int(myString) ?? 0
```

For you example it will be:

```
let spentBudgetInt = Int(spentBudget) ?? 0
```